# Zend Navigation: Where should I load the ACL 'Role' in a private application

Tags: php, zend-auth, zend-navigation, zend-acl

I am working on a 'private' application, you must be logged in to do anything at all. This gives me a bit of a an issue loading the role for Zend Navigation. Currently I am 'init'ing Zend Navigation in my bootstrap; that was fine until I added ACL to Zend Nav. The issue is that I want to load the 'userRole' from my auth storage, but there will not be storage yet until the user logs in, so that gets me a 'Trying to get property of non-object' warning at the login page. This is because before login, there is nothing in auth's storage, so `auth->userRole` is 'nothing' because `auth->getInstance()->getIdentity()->???` would be empty, until a user logs in and the auth is configured.

I'm not using Zend Nav at the login page, in fact I have an alternate layout for the login page (no nav at all); `'if !$auth->hasIdentity'` (false) use the login layout, only show the login page for that matter system-wide, as I said the application is completely private so defaulting to a 'guest' role or something like that seems like a 'dirty' approach, because once a user logs in it will have to reconfigure auth anyhow. It just don't seem right to set a generic auth identity just to please the login page.

What I am getting at is, where is a good place to move the 'init' of Zend Nav, or at least move the configure ACL part? May as well move the whole thing?

This is what I have in my bootstrap.php for Zend Navigation:

```
protected function _initNavigation() {
    $this->_logger->info('Bootstrap ' . __METHOD__);

    $this->bootstrap('layout');
    $layout = $this->getResource('layout');
    $view = $layout->getView();
    $config = new Zend_Config_Xml(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/navigation.xml', 'nav');
    $container = new Zend_Navigation($config);
    $acl = new Application_Model_Acl_Acl();
    $role = Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity()->userRole;
    $view->navigation($container)->setAcl($acl)->setRole($role);
}
```

It is the `'$role = Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity()->userRole'` that is empty (or a non-object) at the time bootstrap runs.

All of my ACL takes place either in the controller (at the action) or some may take place in the models at some point, although I don't anticicpate web service or anything, so maybe they will stay in the controller, but I have the flexibility because I have the ACL in the models (that would be the 'domain' right?

I am only using ACL on Zend Nav for layout, user experience purposes; The menu and links I get from Zend Nav will be 'greyed', non-existant, or active (and visible) according to the user role, for example a 'user' role will not get many 'admin' options, and this is re-enforced by ACL in the controller so one could not simply type the url and get to an area either.

My other thought was that maybe I should be thinking of moving my login into the bootstrap for this situation, but I'm not sure that is a good idea either?

---

**EDIT:**
This is the code that I put into a Front Controller Plugin:

```
class Plugins_Controller_ZendNavInit extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract {

        public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request) {

            $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();

            if ($auth->hasIdentity()) {

                $config = new Zend_Config_Xml(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/navigation.xml', 'nav');
                $container = new Zend_Navigation($config);
                $acl = new Application_Model_Acl_Acl();

                $layout = Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance();
                $view = $layout->getView();

                $role = Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity()->userRole;
                $view->navigation($container)->setAcl($acl)->setRole($role);
            }
        }
    }
```

Works great; I of course, had to register my plugin just like any other. I also moved my Auth checking to a front-controller plugin too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could build an anonymous role before login and handle a very short ACL policy for anonymous users.
Check [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943940/using-zend-auth-to-secure-all-controllers/4944672#4944672) for example on how to catch unauthentified users on PreDispatch with an Auth Plugin.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will look at it this afternoon and get back. It makes 'default user' idea not sound so 'dirty' :)

Comment: I think this (what you suggested) is the solution that I am going to go for, create kind of a pseudo role for the 'login page' and treat it like its the 'login page's' role, who gets logged out when a user logs in; basically just 'cearIdentity()' before writing the new auth to storage. Thanks for the link and taking the time to give an answer.

Comment: For future onlookers, I posted the code that I used in my new Front Controller Plugin in an edit in my original quest (above).

Answer (score 1):

I would not pull it directly from the Auth storage. If you pull it from Zend_Auth and during that users session the user's role is changed, you will either have to force a logout/login or update the info in the Zend_Auth storage. I find it easier to setup a Role class and perform the logic to determine the role there or set a default (guest) role. The User role class extends my User model and implements Zend_Acl_Role_Interface. I can then query the db from within the Role class. I started implementing this a day or so ago but here is an example:

```
<?php
```

class Zfcms_Acl_Role_User extends Zfcms_Model_Users implements Zend_Acl_Role_Interface
{

```
/**
 * Unique id of Role
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $_roleId;
public $_inheritsFrom = 'guest';
public $_defaultRole = 'user';

/**
 * Sets the Role identifier
 *
 * @param  string $id
 * @return void
 * Defined by Zend_Acl_Role_Interface; returns the Role identifier
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getRoleId()
{
    //$auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
    if(Zend_Auth::getInstance()->hasIdentity()) 
    {
        $this->_roleId = self::getUserRoleById(Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity()->user_id);
        return $this->_roleId;
    } 
    elseif(!Zend_Auth::getInstance()->hasIdentity() && !isset($this->role))
    {
        //return 'guest';
        return (string) new Zfcms_Acl_Role_Guest();
    } else {
        throw new Zend_Controller_Action_Exception('Invalid user roleId', 110);
    }
}
public function getDefaultRole()
{
    return $this->_defaultRole;
}
public function getPrivsByRole($role)
{
   //TODO: Design db table to hold privs
}
private function setPrivs()
{
   //TODO: implement
}
/**
 * Defined by Zend_Acl_Role_Interface; returns the Role identifier
 * Proxies to getRoleId()
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function __toString()
{
    return $this->getRoleId();
}
public function getUserRoleById($id)
{
    $this->_id = $id;
    $query = $this->select()
                  ->from('users', array('user_id', 'role'))
                  ->where('user_id = ?', $this->_id);

    $result = $this->fetchAll($query);
    foreach($result as $userRole)
    {
        $role = $userRole->role;
    }
    return $role;
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for posting your method. I am going to take a closer look at this, the way I ended up doing it works well for the project I was working on at the time but I had concern (in the back of my mind) for future projects for the reason you stated (logout/in).